# Programmatically Update the Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK in facebook developer console

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to programmatically update the Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK in the developer settings of facebook.
I cannot seem to find any documentation regarding this

Comment: No there is not. Why do you need to do it programmatically?